# extjs: call function after modal dialog html dom is ready

Tags: extjs

I am having a requirement where on clicking of a button I have to bring a extjs modal dialog and after the html in the modal dialog is ready, I want to capture a DOM element present in the html content of the dialog. Below is the html content:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path to extjs installation folder>\extjs\resources\css\ext-all.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path to extjs installation folder>\extjs\adapter\ext\ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<path to extjs installation folder>\extjs\ext-all.js"></script>
<script>
    Ext.onReady(function(){
        var button = Ext.get('modal-btn');
        button.on('click', showModal);
    });

    var showModal = function(){
        var win;
        if(!win){
            win = new Ext.Window({
                modal:true,
                layout:'fit',
                width:500,
                height:300,
                closeAction:'hide',
                plain: true,
                items: new Ext.Panel({
                    frame:true,
                    collapsible:true,
                    items:[{
                        html:'<object id="renderedObjId" width=760 height=350></object>'
                    }]
                }), 

                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Close',
                    handler: function(){
                        win.hide();
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
        win.show(this);
    }
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="modalDialogForm">
    <input type="button" id="modal-btn" value="Click"/><br /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to capture the object present inside the html content of the modal dialog represented using **renderedObjId**. Ihave t update the content of this html. Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get html content. You can use `afterrender` event of [`Ext.panel.Panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#event-afterrender) and get your element in a handler. In the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o1t) there are shown two ways.

```
items: new Ext.Panel({
    frame: true,
    collapsible: true,
    items: [{
         html: '<object id="renderedObjId" width=760 height=350></object>'
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (cmp) {
            var htmlOb;
            // #1
            htmlOb = document.getElementById('renderedObjId');
            console.log(htmlOb.innerHTML);
            console.log(htmlOb.innerText);
            console.log(htmlOb.textContent);
            // #2
            htmlOb = Ext.get('renderedObjId').dom;
            console.log(htmlOb.innerHTML);
            console.log(htmlOb.innerText);
            console.log(htmlOb.textContent);
        }
    }
}),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the code works like a charm in extjs higher version. We are using extjs 2.2.1 on which this code is not working. It will be really helpful if you can let me know what change I need to do it to work on 2.2.1 version

Comment: Wow, 2.2.1 is too old. I can't get SDK, neither fiddle can deliver. If you can give me a link, i'll try it.